# ExChange columns with rows in powershell

Tags: powershell

after a couple of hours I need a help with PS script.

I have an array where :

```
computername   Folder  Size
PC1              A      123
PC1              B      18
PC1              C      356
PC2              A      589
PC2              B      58
PC2              C      59
PC2              D      89
```

I need somehow exchange the columns with rows where result will be as following:

```
         Folder_A   Folder_B  Folder_C  Folder_D
PC1      123        18        356
PC2      589        58         59       89
```

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Why not just create a csv from your data and use Excel's Pivot to do the heavy work. After all, it's just an output issue?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://powershell.org/2012/07/powershell-pivot-tables/) can give you some pointers if you like to use powershell

Comment: show what contain 1 element of array, and what is it type(may be you have array of objects with properties)

Comment: Thank you. The New-PSPivotTable cmdlet did what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume `$array` does contain your array of objects with the properties specified in your columns, you can do the following:

```
$output = $array | Group-Object computername | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{Computer=$_.Name}
    $_.Group | Foreach-Object {
        $hash.Add(('Folder_'+$_.Folder),$_.Size)
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
    }
}

$output | Format-List
```

`$output` will contain an array of objects. Since those objects will likely have different properties, you may have display issues in your console. For example, `PC1` will not have `Folder_D` and since it is the first item in the array, the default output for all remaining objects will be missing `Folder_D`. This is why I added the `Format-List` command, ***which should be used for display purposes only and not for further processing***.

Regarding missing columns in the output, you have a couple of options. One, you can sort your objects to where the one with the most properties is first in the list. Two, you can use additional logic to predetermine your full list of properties and then apply those properties to all objects. See below for predetermining the folder list:

```
$Folders = $array.Folder | Select -Unique
$output = $array | Group-Object computername | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{Computer=$_.Name}
    foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
        $hash.Add(('Folder_'+$Folder),$null)
    }
    $_.Group | Foreach-Object {
        $hash.$('Folder_'+$_.Folder) = $_.Size
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash

}

$output | Format-Table
```

Comment: Was thinking the same, but this unfortunately leaves out the `Folder_D` column.

Comment: @Theo, I changed to `Format-List`, unfortunately.

Comment: Perfect, This is usable for me as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Theo, I just went ahead and added another variant that lists the same columns for all the objects.

Comment: I solved the Folder_D issue with adding a header into csv file with PS(by looping all available folders in array) and then export all data(saved as your above script - per server into another array variable) into this exact csv file. It sorted out automatically the Size per found Folder. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Nicely done completing the headers in all objects. (+1)